# Maze following path cut out useless paths

Tags: algorithm, path, maze

I have a player in a maze(2d) without any access to the maze (so no A* really practical, isn't it) I just can say the player go and check whether there is a wall in front of you or not. I am using the way of choosing the "rightest" path on every fork to find a collectable. To find the way back to the spawn I could just always chose the "leftest" path on every fork and check whether this was the spawn(this is possible). But I know the path I walked there (made a list and added every step I did(go forward, turn left, turn right), easy to walk this recording backwards). But while going the way through the maze I went through a whole part that has only one entrance and is completely empty and this is recorded in the movement-recording. So while going back I will walk through this part again. Can I somehow find the same movements inverted again? I looked for fixed patterns and removed them like "rotated180;go;rotated180;go" or "rotated360"(which is internally four times rotated90). But how can I make it not fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me why you need to go back - can't you just reposition yourself to where you started?

Anyway, if you record each position in the list in addition to the movement, then when going back you can check if the square you are about to enter (return to) appears further back in the list (closer to your origin), and if it does, skip to that part of the list, thereby skipping the detour you made into that empty section of the maze going out.

Comment: I do not have any coordinates. But I could calculate relative ones. I will try it. I just control the movement not the explicit position of the player. I need to go back and drop the collectable there.

Comment: Relative coordinates would be the way to go, then.

Comment: I did it with the relative coordinates. Spawn is vector 0,0 and I have a vector where the player is looking too. It was quite easy to implement, but not to get the idea ... somehow. To remove a unnessescary path I remove the span between a first and last occurence of a point.